# Efficient approach of checking for dict keywords in huge list of sentences

Tags: python

I need to check if each key in myDict appear in the sentences of huge text, about 2million words. If key is found, then print key and all the sentences where it is found.The program creates dict from myList.

> **myList**: ['Luke/NP 1/NUM', '1/NUM Whereas/P many/ADJ have/V undertaken/VN to/TO compile/V a/DET statement/N of/P the/DET facts/N that/WH are/V given/VN full/ADJ credence/N among/P us/PRO ,/,', '2/NUM just/ADV as/P those/DET who/WH from/P -LSB-/( the/DET -RSB-/) beginning/VG became/VD eyewitnesses/N and/CNJ attendants/N of/P the/DET message/N delivered/VN these/DET to/TO us/PRO ,/,', ...]

Expected result is in the form:

**and ['CNJ']**

> 2/NUM just/ADV as/P those/DET who/WH from/P -LSB-/( the/DET -RSB-/) beginning/VG became/VD eyewitnesses/N **and/CNJ** attendants/N of/P the/DET message/N delivered/VN these/DET to/TO us/PRO ,/,

**among ['P']**

> 1/NUM Whereas/P many/ADJ have/V undertaken/VN to/TO compile/V a/DET statement/N of/P the/DET facts/N that/WH are/V given/VN full/ADJ credence/N **among/P** us/PRO ,/,

**to ['TO']**

> 1/NUM Whereas/P many/ADJ have/V undertaken/VN **to/TO** compile/V a/DET statement/N of/P the/DET facts/N that/WH are/V given/VN full/ADJ credence/N among/P us/PRO ,/,
>
> 2/NUM just/ADV as/P those/DET who/WH from/P -LSB-/( the/DET -RSB-/) beginning/VG became/VD eyewitnesses/N and/CNJ attendants/N of/P the/DET message/N delivered/VN these/DET **to/TO** us/PRO ,/,
>
> ............

My code works on a small amount but delays on a huge amount of the text. Please guys, I believe there is efficient way to handle this. Below is part of the code:

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

dic = defaultdict(list)

for sent in myList:
    wt_tupl = [wt.split('/') for wt in sent.split()]
    for (w,t) in wt_tupl:
        if w in dic and t in dic[w]:
            continue
        else:
            dic[w].append(t)

for k,v in dic.items():
    print k,v
    for i, sent in enumerate(f):
        wts = zip(*[wt.split('/') for wt in sent.split()])
        line = wts[0]

        if k in line:              #guess my problem is here!
            print sent.strip()
            
    print
    print
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your problem is going over the entire file for each word in the dictionary. Instead, try going over the file only once, checking every word if it is in the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks tbrisker for the pointer. I am kinda Python newbie :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is going over the entire file for each word in the dictionary. 
Instead, try going over the file only once, checking every word if it is in the dictionary.